# Change a single node's content in an element with XSL whilst copying the rest

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML which features a fair number of attributes in each element, and sometimes I need to format one or two attributes if some condition is met. I thought I'd do this with XSL.

So inside my template in the XSL file I have the following:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="ytd &lt; 0.000000001 or interest &lt; 0.000000001">
    <xsl:element name="Report">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="ytd&lt; 0.000000001">
          <xsl:element name="ytd">0</xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="interest &lt; 0.000000001">
          <xsl:element name="interest">0</xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

The operations for the YTD and interest fields work as I expect them to, essentially rounding down small amounts to zero for me. The problem is the otherwise clause; I seem to misunderstand how to use the copy-of. I want the other n attributes of a Report element to be copied over as they are in the original XML. Problem is with this current template I get output like the following for a Report which has a very small ytd:

```
<Report><ytd>0</ytd></Report>
```

So obviously I'm not copying the rest of the element properly. Any pointers?

EDIT:
A sample input XML file might be:

```
<Reports>
  <Report>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <account>Saver</account>
    <ytd>100</ytd>
    <interest>0.5</ytd>
    <cosigned>false</cosigned>
  </Report>
  <Report>
    <name>Steve</name>
    <account>Gold Account</account>
    <ytd>0.0000000001</ytd>
    <interest>0.0000000001</ytd>
    <cosigned>false</cosigned>
  </Report>
</Reports>
```

And desired output would be:

```
<Reports>
  <Report>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <account>Saver</account>
    <ytd>100</ytd>
    <interest>0.5</ytd>
    <cosigned>false</cosigned>
  </Report>
  <Report>
    <name>Steve</name>
    <account>Gold Account</account>
    <ytd>0</ytd>
    <interest>0</ytd>
    <cosigned>false</cosigned>
  </Report>
</Reports>
```

(Obviously I'm just mocking that up but hopefully you can see what I mean)

Thanks,
Dave.

Comment: Consider to show us the relevant XML input sample you want to transform, the output you want, the output you get and current code so that we can reproduce the problem. So far you have shown a snippet of XSLT where we do not even know what the XML input is and what the current context node is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do what you want is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ytd[ . &lt; 0.000000001 ] | interest[ . &lt; 0.000000001]">
        <xsl:copy>0</xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- Use identity rule (see first template above) to copy everything as is
- Override elements as required

Comment: Well that just makes me look ridiculous :( Thanks mate! For extra credit... Is there a way of making those silly 0.000000001 look a bit cleaner, perhaps with exponential notation? The number I'm actually looking for is significantly smaller!

Comment: You are welcome. Well, use what you like. Do you mean something like 1.0e-9?

Comment: Yep. Problem is I've either got the syntax wrong or I've hit some sort of limit:


ERROR:  'Syntax error in 'ytd[ . < 1.0e-300 ] | interest[ . < 1.0e-300]'.'

Comment: Ah, I see now what you are asking. Sorry, don't think you will be able to do that kind of check :).

Comment: A possible shortcut could be `ytd[starts-with(.,'0.000')]` even if this will pass also for any number starting with 0.000 (e.g. 0.0001).